# xcode: auto table height in view controller

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

I need to create a table view inside the view controller, but the problem is that the height for 4s & 5 is different. So what happens is that the table view fits to the bottom on 4s, but on iphone 5 the table height is stop at the middle of the view.

How to I make the table height to auto fit till the bottom of the view for both devices?

Thank!

Comment: Check out [auto layout](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1).

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

Comment: this actually created another table on top of my existing table instead of resized by existing table

Comment: here just a example, you should set tableView like this, not to copy the code and use in project directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the help of Auto Layout:

```
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] init;
//Add Auto Layout constraint For TableView
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];

constraint=[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.tableView attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0 constant:0.0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

These constraints will work on all devices and manage width and height of your TableView as well.